# Deleting all attachments

Tags: .net, ravendb

What's the easiest way to purge **all** attachments from a RavenDB database?

I'm using the .NET API, but I'm open to doing a raw HTTP call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will go through all attachments in the database and delete them one at a time.

```
private void DeleteAllAttachments(IDocumentStore store)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var header = store.DatabaseCommands
            .GetAttachmentHeadersStartingWith("", 0, 1)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (header == null) return;
        store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteAttachment(header.Key, null);
    }
}
```

You could probably optimize it a bit by taking a larger page size, but since you are deleting anyway, it likely won't matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is not a built in option to get all attachments for a database. But you can do  the following:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("databases/YourDatabaseName/static").Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var files = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<AttachmentInformation>>().Result;

foreach (var fileDetail in files)
{
    store.DatabaseCommands.DeleteAttachment(fileDetail.Key, null);
}
```

For this to work you need the following POCO. And to a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client v5. You can remove this requirement if you just do ReadAsString and parse the response content yourself or with another json parser.

```
public class AttachmentInformation
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the size.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The size.</value>
    public int Size { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The key.</value>
    public string Key { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the metadata.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The metadata.</value>
    public object Metadata { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the etag.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The etag.</value>
    public Guid Etag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but that function *does* exist, in `GetAttachmentHeadersStartingWith`, which can take an empty string if you want them all.  Still, nice to see some out-of-the-box thinking and use of the HTTP api.  Nice work.